# MS Excel : Unable to control radio buttons in an Excel file

Tags: excel, button

I have this Excel file that has 5 radio buttons in each row.

I find that when I select a radio button in a row , it deselects the radio button in the previous row. I want my selections to be saved with the rule of one per row. How can I achieve that?

With Regards
Sri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it seem this solution only works with activex option buttons

Give all radio buttons in the same row the same groupname
(Can be changed with Design mode(design mode can be toggled when clicking on the Design mode button in the developer tab) on clicking on the button, properties and change the groupname there)

Found a solution for other option button (easier):

http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2010/03/24/select-answers-with-excel-option-buttons/

Comment: Thanks for responding , I find that 'Design Mode' & 'Groupings' are not enabled for me. How do I enable them?